# Google Drive integration 3rd party cloud storage providers

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there any way to integrate Google Drive with 3rd party cloud (public or privated) providers. I mean, can you create a folder whose content is linked to another cloud provider (i.e. Dropbox or a Private Cloud in your corporation), or all the content you'll see in your Google Drive must reside in Google?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in a way that the UX would make sense. You'd need to implement your own file viewer which is a mashup of Drive and Dropbox etc file store.